# What DB rights needs the Reindex tool in Magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I wonder what user rights needs the reindex tool in magento to work, as having it like this now, it doesn't seem to be working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think these:

- CREATE
- REFERENCES
- INDEX
- DROP
- LOCK TABLES